# python mechanize file upload UnicodeDecode error

Tags: python, file-upload, mechanize

So I have a little script that I would like to use to upload some PDFs to my citation-site-of-choice (citeulike.org)

Thing is its not working. It does this:

> ```
> so want to upload /Users/willwade/Dropbox/Papers/price_promoting_643127.pdf  to  12589610
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "citeuupload.py", line 167, in <module>
>     cureader.parseUserBibTex()
>   File "citeuupload.py", line 160, in parseUserBibTex
>     self.uploadFileToCitation(b['citeulike-article-id'],self.localpapers+fileorfalse)
>   File "citeuupload.py", line 138, in uploadFileToCitation
>     resp = self.browser.submit()
>   File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 541, in submit
>   File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 203, in open
>   File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 230, in _mech_open
>   File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/mechanize/_opener.py", line 193, in open
>   File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/mechanize/_urllib2_fork.py", line 344, in _open
>   File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/mechanize/_urllib2_fork.py", line 332, in _call_chain
>   File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/mechanize/_urllib2_fork.py", line 1142, in http_open
>   File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/mechanize/_urllib2_fork.py", line 1115, in do_open
>   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 955, in request
>     self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
>   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 989, in _send_request
>     self.endheaders(body)
>   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 951, in endheaders
>     self._send_output(message_body)
>   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 809, in _send_output
>     msg += message_body
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 544: ordinal not in range(128)
> ```

and the code:

> ```
> def uploadFileToCitation(self,artid,file):
>     print 'so want to upload', file, ' to ', artid
>     self.browser.open('http://www.citeulike.org/user/'+cUser+'/article/'+artid)
>     self.browser.select_form(name="fileupload_frm")
>     self.browser.form.add_file(open(file, 'rb'), 'application/pdf', file, name='file')
>     try:
>         resp = self.browser.submit()
>         self.wait_for_api_limit()
>     except mechanize.HTTPError, e:
>         print 'error'
>         print e.getcode()
>         print resp.read()
>         exit()
> ```

NB: I can see it's reading in the file correctly (and it does exist). Also note that I'm doing this elsewhere

> ```
>     self.browser = mechanize.Browser()
>     self.browser.set_handle_robots(False)
>     self.browser.addheaders = [
>       ("User-agent", 'me@me.com citeusyncpy/1.0'),
>     ]
> ```

[Full code is here](https://gist.github.com/willwade/6288982)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to check this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993175/how-do-i-post-non-ascii-characters-using-httplib-when-content-type-is-applicati).

*`To clarify, the message is constructed in httplib from the method, URL, headers, etc. If any of these is Unicode, the whole string gets converted to Unicode (I presume this is normal Python behavior). Then if you try to append a UTF-8 string you get the error I described in the original question...`*

From looks of it's a problem with encoding that proper header can fix.

Also you can check this [issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue11898).

Comment: thanks for that. To confirm [the patch in the issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue11898) @ton1c mentioned solved the problem